# jQuery exist text in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some problem with jquery function. Please help me ...

So, i have this

```
$("#NewPost").live("focus", function(){ 
   $(this).animate({height:112},300); 
}).bind("keydown", function(e) { 
   e = e || window.event; 
   if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.ctrlKey) {sendPostY();} 
});
```

and this ..

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest("#NewPost").length) return;
        $("#NewPost").animate({height:26},300);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Global problem in the text. If text exists in #NewPost it should not change CSS height on click on document. But, if #NewPost don't have this text, it must be change CSS height on click on document.

Please, sorry for my English, i'm from Ukraine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        var newPost = $(event.target).closest("#NewPost");
        if (newPost.length > 0 && !!newPost.text()) return;
        $("#NewPost").animate({height:26},300);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but your changes not work. Please give me such more versions .. Thank you!